# Why does sorting array of enums with Swift 5 give different results?

Tags: swift, swift5

I don't know whether it is a bug or a feature but sorting array of enums give different result with each run. Here is a basic code to test it.

```
enum Tag: String {
    case bold, italic, underline
}

extension Tag: Comparable {
    static func <(lhs: Tag, rhs: Tag) -> Bool {
        return lhs.hashValue < rhs.hashValue
    }
}

let tags:[Tag] = [.bold, .italic, .underline].sorted()
print(tags.map {$0.rawValue})
```

Comment: @VatsalManot Right. I wasn't paying attention. I'll remove my comment.

Comment: @Meanteacher The answers here are misleading: `hashValue` is based on a function. Meaning for a given value, the hashValue of it would be the same. Unless you store it and then build it again later at a different time. From the shared link it says Random seeding” means that hashValue properties will return **different values on each execution of a Swift program.** ie it doesn't change 'during' an Xcode build. Aside from that: it's incorrect compare enums based on their String rawvalues. How do you compare "john", "Peter" and "TJ"? The OP hasn't state how he wants them to be compared...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure it's because of [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hashable/1540917-hashvalue):

> Hash values are not guaranteed to be equal across different executions
>   of your program. Do not save hash values to use during a future
>   execution.

If you change your Comparison method to:

```
return lhs.rawValue < rhs.rawValue
```

that should work.

Comment: `hashValue` is based on a function. Meaning for a given value, the hashValue of it would be the same. Unless you store it and then build it again later at a different time. From the shared link it says Random seeding” means that hashValue properties will return **different values on each execution of a Swift program.** ie it doesn't change 'during' an Xcode build. Aside from that: it's incorrect compare enums based on their String rawvalues. How do you compare "john", "Peter" and "TJ"? The OP hasn't state how he wants them to be compared...

Comment: @Honey I was looking for deterministic order. I have learned that hashValue is not deterministic. This answer is sufficient for my use case.

Comment: @Honey can you remove that -1 for me, bud?

Comment: @leahyjwilliam I gave you +1 and accepted your answer. I don't know who gave you the -1.

Answer (score 2):

**The simple answer:**

In your example, you are comparing using the `hashValue` of a `String`. Swift 5's hashing algorithms differ from that of Swift 4.

**The answer you're looking for:**

Don't sort strings (or any type for that matter) based on their hashes, it's not what you're looking for. What you're looking for is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

The implementation you want is probably this:

```
extension Tag: Comparable {
    static func <(lhs: Tag, rhs: Tag) -> Bool {
        return lhs.rawValue < rhs.rawValue
    }
}
```

`rawValue` being the raw `String` value of the enum.

A hash value is the product of a [hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function), which has absolutely nothing to do with sorting.

**Bonus info:**

For those astute observers wondering why the hash values are different every Swift run, [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/14913) is the breakdown.

Comment: It would be neat to know why the hashes are different each time, is this a collision?

Comment: @Alex Swift's standard library hashing functions now use a random seed per program execution (as discussed [here](https://forums.swift.org/t/psa-the-stdlib-now-uses-randomly-seeded-hash-values/10789)).

Comment: "The implementation you want is probably this:" Why don't you ask him? Normally  you don't want to compare "Alex" vs. "TJ".